# Android and field of useage

Tags: android

Before I start to develop an application I really want to know that we can only use android Sdk on Android phones or can we use the android Sdk to develop other things like iPad, iPhone also etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Android SDK to develop software for the Android OS. So every device that is running Android OS, you should be able to develop software for.

The IPad, the IPhone, etc uses a different OS.